# How do I create a custom "merge" method for hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hashmap

How do I implement a "custom_merge" method?

```
h1 = {a: 1, c: 2} 
h2 = {a: 3, b: 5}
```

This is a standard "merge" method implementation:

```
h1.merge(h2) # => {:a=>3, :c=>2, :b=>5}
```

My desired "custom_merge" method should implement:

```
h1.custom_merge(h2) # {a: [1, 3], b: 5, c: 2}
```

Answer (score 6):

No need the custom_merge method. Ruby core supplied [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) with block will help you out.

```
h1 = {a: 1, c: 2} 
h2 = {a: 3, b: 5} 
h3 = h1.merge(h2){|k,o,n| [o,n]}
h3
# => {:a=>[1, 3], :c=>2, :b=>5}
```

Comment: amazing speed, Priti!

Comment: @SergRa6n Yes.. I am in ruby mode today.. :)))

Comment: It's not necessary to thank people for their edits. It's an expectation that we do that to improve Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hash
  def custom_merge other
    merge(other){|_, *a| a}
  end
end
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?